# autodesk forge potree problem-BufferGeometry.addAttribute() is deprecated. Use BufferGeometry.setAttribute() instead

Tags: javascript, autodesk-forge, point-clouds

I am going to proceed with importing point cloud through potree with the following example file.
https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-extensions

I was working with the example file, but I got an error "BufferGeometry.addAttribute() is deprecated. Use BufferGeometry.setAttribute() instead". This problem also occurs in the example file driven site. It happens on other computers as well. Here is the error I got:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bsjfm.png)

If this extension works normally, you should see the point cloud converted from the port tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for the heads-up. The Potree library was ported to the viewer couple years ago, when the viewer was still using WebGL. Now the viewer is using WebGL2 which is why the port is causing issues. In order to get it working again, I'd suggest that you disable WebGL2 support in the viewer by passing the following options to [viewer.start](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/Viewing/Viewer3D/#start-url-options-onsuccesscallback-onerrorcallback-initoptions) (the first four params can be ignored):

```js
viewer.start(undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, {
    webglInitParams: {
        useWebGL2: false
    }
});
```

After that I was able to load the point cloud again. Here's a branch of one of our code samples with this modification: https://github.com/autodesk-platform-services/aps-simple-viewer-nodejs/tree/sample/potree.

Also, note that the `addAttribute` vs `setAttribute` are just deprecation warnings, not errors. In the code branch above I've updated the `potree.js` script as well so that the warnings do not appear anymore.

Comment: hello. thank you for the reply.
The link you shared says "This is not the webpage you are looking for."

Comment: Oops, sorry. We're in the process of migrating samples between different github orgs, and this sample hasn't been made public yet. I've made the code available on my github account: https://github.com/petrbroz/aps-simple-viewer-nodejs/tree/sample/potree.